# How to resize the jquery dialog in x-axis after reaching max width, it should resize in y-axis?

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

In my app, I am having a jquery dialog, I need customized resize, i have used resizable true, maxwidth properties, Now i want the jquery dialog to resize first in x-axis and after reaching the max-width it should resize in y-axis, My code as below

```
 $("#dialogHolder").dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    title : "Tools",
    height : 100,
    resizable : true,
    minWidth : 300,
    maxWidth: 600,
    zIndex:1050
});
```